# Xcode 4.3 doesn't link to ZbarSDK properly

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

Followed the instructions for installing the zbarsdk and I am unable to link it properly ever since upgrading to xcode 4.3.  The ZbarSDK folder is also shown as blue instead of the yellow folder when it is usually linked.  Anyone experiencing the same issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I found out I was not checking the "Create groups for any added folders" option.